# Verbs that follow an amount of time, singular or plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, time

Which one is grammatically correct?

> 1. One hour and a half is all you have left.
> 2. One hour and a half are all you have left.
> 3. Two hours is all you have left.
> 4. Two hours are all you have left.

And why?

Comment: Is this from a standardized test?

Answer (score 3):

The amount of time is a single unit even though it is expressed by describing an aggregated number of units of time. When that amount is the subject of the sentence or clause, it takes a singular verb.

Answer (score 2):

*Two hours* is a single unit of time, so would take a singular verb; it refers to the whole time span that lasts 120 minutes. However, if you split the two hours and make them distinct you would need a plural.

> Two hours, one today and one next week, are needed to complete the test.

The difference is that the hours are distinct rather than part of a single time span.

Also, the English idiom would be "one and a half hours" rather than "one hour and a half."

Comment: The most common English expression for 1.5 hours is *"an hour and a half"*. [See Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=one+hour+and+a+half%2C+one+and+a+half+hours%2C+an+hour+and+a+half&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cone%20hour%20and%20a%20half%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cone%20and%20a%20half%20hours%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Can%20hour%20and%20a%20half%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: But then "two hours are needed to complete the test" should also be singular, right? Why is it "are" here?