# Over a billion years (is/ are) required for a diamond to be formed. Should the verb be singular or plural in this case and why?

Tags: verb-agreement

Does the subject (Over a billion years) function as a single unit of measurement here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plural or singular {verb form} when stating that an amount is enough](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112109/plural-or-singular-when-stating-that-an-amount-is-enough) See also [subject-verb agreement with _years_ measurement as subject](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/288345/subject-verb-agreement-with-years-measurement-as-subject). And [verbs that follow an amount of time ... singular or plural?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131960/verbs-that-follow-an-amount-of-time-singular-or-plural/131962#131962) ...

Comment: And [plural / singular verb agreement with units](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41155/plural-singular-verb-agreement-with-units). And [More than 1000 gallons of paint is/are sold each day](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80822/more-than-1000-gallons-of-paint-is-are-sold-each-day). // Here, few would not use notional agreement (... is) rather than formal agreement (... are), the interval, as you say, being considered as unary.

Comment: Why torture yourself? Whichever plurality you decide to use, at least *some* people will think you made the wrong choice. Just give yourself an easy life and go for ***It takes** over a billion years **to form** a diamond*, same as most sensible native Anglophones

Answer (score 1):

yes,I think the verb should be singular here, because over a billion years as the subject of the sentence should be treated as a whole noun.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).